# How to create spring controller for auto convert response jaxbelement to xml

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, jaxb

I have spring contoller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/fake_cp")
public class FakeContentProvider {
    @RequestMapping(value="/request")
    public @ResponseBody JAXBElement<MetaRequest> request(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute FaceContentProviderCommand command
            )
            throws Exception {
        ru.icb.cpaclick.controller.jaxb.MetaRequest request = new ru.icb.cpaclick.controller.jaxb.MetaRequest();
        request.setAccessUrl("http://accessUrl.ru");
        request.setErrorUrl("http://errorUrl.ru");
        request.setShortdesc("This is short desc");
        request.setLoadUrl("http://loadru.ru");
        request.setTariffclass(20501);
        return new ObjectFactory().createRequest(request);

}
```

server return answer:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.writeWithMessageConverters(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:993)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.handleHttpEntityResponse(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:952)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.getModelAndView(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Could not find acceptable representation
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
[application/octet-stream, */*, text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1, */*, */*, application/xml, text/xml, application/*+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, application/xml, text/xml, application/*+xml]
05.08.2011 10:57:08 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
```

How to create response converter for jaxbelement, or how to config spring?

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not the best way to handle REST or SOAP services in Spring.

A spring mvc controller is best used for rendering web pages. If you want to handle REST or SOAP services, you're better off adding an Apache XCF servlet integrated with Spring.

Using xjc (REST) and wsimport (SOAP) you can use a contract first approach to generated the classes and interfaces related to the service you want to expose. 
Based on that you create an endpoint in the xcf configuration and your're done.